# Check if, for any value of c, the function is a solution of the differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> **Question:**
>
> To show that $$y = ce^{-2x} + e^{-x}$$ is a solution to $$ y' + 2y = 
>   e^{-x}$$

I set out by 
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}+2y=e^{-x}$$

am I going to use an integrating factor because of the $2y$?

Comment: Just plug it in an calculate?

Comment: David don't forget to accept one of the answers clicking the 'V' in the left side of the answer

Answer (score 2):

To check if the given $y$ is a solution to the given differential equation, you just compute $y'$ and substitute $y'$ and $y$ into the differential equation.

Comment: Following this I get y' = -2ce^(-2x)+-e^-x

That doesn't follow what it says.

Comment: @DavidScidmore What do you get when you substitute your expression for $y'$ and the given expression for $y$ into the original differential equation?

Comment: Thank you, I was just missing that step for some reason. I'm a little panicked due to having 4 exams next week. I have an Organic Chem 2 and Linear Algebra Differential equations exam with in 4 hours of each other.  So having some brain farting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track. You have to introduce the integrating factor due to the $2y$.

The solution will go as:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}+2y=e^{-x}$$

The integrating factor will be $e^{2x}$.

So we have that,
$$ e^{2x}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+2ye^{2x}=e^x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(ye^{2x})=e^x$$
$$d(ye^{2x})=e^x dx$$

Integrating both sides, we get
$$\int d(ye^{2x})=\int e^x dx$$
$$ye^{2x}=e^x+c$$
$$y=e^{-x}+ce^{-2x}$$ where $c$ is any arbitrary constant of integration.

Hope this helps you.